# How to change RGB to CMYK color specific in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I am using adobe illustrator cc 2018. I have a color #ff32cb. I want to convert it to CMYK same as it is looking. If i use this code in cmyk then its not same.(see image attached. Right color is rgb, i want same in left in cmyk) Please help me how to do it. Thanks[image]

Comment: The Real World interferes here: no mix of cyan, magenta, yellow, and black can produce that bright color.

Comment: You can't. That colour is out of gamut for CMYK printing.  If you try to use it in Photoshop, in a CMYK document, it will show the "out of gamut" warning.  It might be possible to use a fluorescent spot colour to get something close, but certainly not in CMYK printing.

Answer (score 3):

An RGB color is a set of values which tells your screen how much light to emit:

[image]

A CMYK color, on the other hand, is a set of values which tells a printing device which raster percentages of the CMYK inks to print:

[image]

A color profile is used for converting from RGB to CMYK to ensure the greatest possible color likeness. You need to use the color profile recommended by your print shop.

The conversion is not perfect. Some colors which are possible to show on your screen isn't possible to print on paper with the four standard CMYK inks.

This diagram from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space#/media/File:CIE1931xy_gamut_comparison.svg) shows the so-called *gamut* of RGB and CMYK color spaces (the colored gradient area shows all visible colors - the colors are symbolic):

[image]

I simply want to show how a CMYK print has fewer colors than an RGB screen can display. And how an RGB screen has fewer colors than the human eye can perceive.

#### What to do

- **If you need to use standard CMYK print:** Learn to live with the limitations. Design with less vibrant colors and acknowledge the difference between screen and paper. The human eye is very adaptable so the print *might* look vibrant enough on its own even though it looks dull compared to the screen.
- **If your print shop provides it:** Add a spot color to the print. Pantone 806 or 807 are fluorescent colors which both are pretty close to the color you want.
- **If you only need a few copies:** Find a high-end digital art print shop. They might be able to get more vibrant colors from your RGB file than you can with standard CMYK conversion (although your color is *very* vibrant).

Comment: FYI: the reason that your 3rd "get more vibrant colors from your RGB file" works, is because a good printer can provide the best *possible* conversion from RGB to the printer's CMYK mix, for its combination of print engine and specific inks. It still won't be as bright as something that actually *emits* light, but usually better than Illustrator's generic conversion.

Comment: @usr2564301 well maybe, but many times they can also employ more than cmyk colors. So if its a 6, 7 or 8 ink system it can produce much better gamuts. The sublimation printer we have can produce nearly same range of color than a tablet, even in chroma, when put on a white aluminium board.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can get as printed in CMYK the same as you have in the right half of your image. Only have a light strong enough - so strong that when the inks have filtered their parts off and the paper has dissipated what it does not reflect, you have as much light left as your screen outputs. You must have a bit stronger light than the standard light where CMYK colors are defined.

In color theory terms you are expecting higher chroma than CMYK colors can produce. In this site we say the same "Your wanted color is out of gamut".

Adobe software users generally pay the premium price what Adobe asks just because Adobe's software has proven it can show what you get and that ability doesn't vanish if you move stuff between different applications.

You can get the right part printed and looking out right in normal light if you order special color which is fluorescent and converts ambient light to magenta. Essentially that color has inbuilt magenta lamp which gets its energy from white light.

You see the same effect quite often. But it's yellow or orange. The safety vests of the on-street workers use also fluorescense.

Comment: Yeah but the color you suggest is not CMYK :)